# Cannot convert python code to kotlin code

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kotlin, http

I have this python code:

```py
import os

from base64 import b64encode
from typing import Union
from hashlib import sha1
from hmac import new

PREFIX = bytes.fromhex("42")
SIG_KEY = bytes.fromhex("F8E7A61AC3F725941E3AC7CAE2D688BE97F30B93")
DEVICE_KEY = bytes.fromhex("02B258C63559D8804321C5D5065AF320358D366F")


def deviceId(data: bytes = None) -> str:
    if isinstance(data, str): data = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
    identifier = PREFIX + (data or os.urandom(20))
    mac = new(DEVICE_KEY, identifier, sha1)
    return f"{identifier.hex()}{mac.hexdigest()}".upper()


def signature(data: Union[str, bytes]) -> str:
    data = data if isinstance(data, bytes) else data.encode("utf-8")
    return b64encode(PREFIX + new(SIG_KEY, data, sha1).digest()).decode("utf-8")
```

I need to convert it to kotlin code. After few hours i wrote this:

```kotlin
import java.util.*
import javax.crypto.Mac
import android.util.Base64
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec


fun String.decodeTheHex(): ByteArray = chunked(2).map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }.toByteArray()

fun ByteArray.toHexString() = joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }


const val HMAC_SHA_1 = "HmacSHA1"
const val NDC_MSG_SIG_KEY = "F8E7A61AC3F725941E3AC7CAE2D688BE97F30B93"
const val DEVICE_ID_KEY = "02B258C63559D8804321C5D5065AF320358D366F"


fun getSignature(data: String): String {
    val mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1")
    mac.init(SecretKeySpec(NDC_MSG_SIG_KEY.decodeTheHex(), HMAC_SHA_1))
    return Base64.encodeToString("42".decodeTheHex() + mac.doFinal(data.toByteArray()), Base64.NO_WRAP)
}

fun getDeviceId(): String {
    val mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1")
    mac.init(SecretKeySpec(DEVICE_ID_KEY.decodeTheHex(), HMAC_SHA_1))
    val bytes = ByteArray(20)
    Random().nextBytes(bytes)
    val id = "42" + bytes.toHexString()
    return (id + mac.doFinal("2".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8) + bytes).toHexString()).uppercase()
}
```

But  the result after compiling is not correct (the app doesn't allow the result, i mean the app, for that i'm sending the request. And i know, that the result from function getDeviceId() is completly wrong). How to convert it?

Comment: Share error or logcat what is actually probelm

Comment: For hex & byteArray conversion, check this:https://github.com/jemshit/WalletConnect/blob/main/walletconnect-core/src/main/java/walletconnect/core/cryptography/HexByteExtensions.kt

For HmacSHA256 check this: https://github.com/jemshit/WalletConnect/blob/main/walletconnect-core/src/main/java/walletconnect/core/cryptography/Cryptography.kt

You can also check their tests, so you can write similar tests

Comment: Arul, there is no error, just incorrect deviceId (from getDeviceId() function). I'm making a http request with this deviceId in data, but the answer: deviceId incorrect. On python it's all OK, but with cotllin - wrong deviceId.

I hope that you understood me